# Digital signature in YAML file. Similar to XMLDSIG

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, digital-signature

XMLDSIG is a digital signature specification for XML document. C# has classes to support XMLDSIG in System.Security.Cryptography.Xml namespace.

I was wondering if there is a digital signature specification for YAML documents. Or in general how would be go about validating the authenticity of the YAML document (as in it has not been tampered).

Idea was to place a digital signature in YAML document and then use the public key at other end to validate it. Not sure if there is any library implemented around this thing in C#, python or go.

I did find something under section **3.2.1.3. Equality** at http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/ that mentions about using canonical form to support digital signature. Not sure if I understand it though.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no specific digital signature format for Yaml. The most common formats are `XMLDsig` for xml, `PAdES` for PDF, `CMS`/`PKCS#7`/`CAdES` for binary data and `JWS` for JSON

Adding a yaml tag with the signature means dealing with the canonicalization of the text that can lead to a headache.

I suggest to wrap the content into a signature container as CMS/PKCS#7 or JWT. For example

```
{
 "yaml": "SGVsbG8=". //yaml as base64
}
```

Or use a detached signature

---

**Canonicalization**
The link you refer is talking about how to represent a number. Note that any changes in the data, or the way in which they are processed to calculate the signature will produce different signatures. So when a text format is used it is needed a well-known 'canonicalization` process to ensure the data is processed by all parties in the same way